# How to stop function overwriting javascript object property and add new property instead?

Tags: javascript

How can I add a new property for each element without overwriting the last property? H2 backgroundColor is overwriting H2 color in this example:

```
var cssObject = {}

function updateAllCSS(element, property, value) {

        cssObject[element] = [property] 
        cssObject[element][property] = value            

}

updateAllCSS('h2', 'color', '#000')
updateAllCSS('h2', 'backgroundColor', '#FFF')


console.log(cssObject.h2.color)
```

Any help would be amazing :)

Comment: I'd recommend against setting styles via JavaScript, and instead suggest adding/removing classes. Styles belong in stylesheets.

Comment: its to build a stylesheet for a CMS

Comment: Note that your code is flawed (apart from your question). `cssObject[element] = [property]` assigns an **array** to `cssObject[element]` with one element. `cssObject[element][property]` otoh sets the **property** `property` of that array to a certain value. You end up with an array having one element and a custom property with the same name, i.e. your array looks like `{0: 'color', 'color': '#000', length: 1}`. The [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide) provides a good introduction to objects and arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new `cssObject[element]` if you don't have one.

```
function updateAllCSS(element, property, value) {
   if (!cssObject[element]) cssObject[element] = {};
   cssObject[element][property] = value            
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, I can now build a CMS stylesheet with this data structure :)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery. It makes it very simple and is really very powerful in manipulation activity. In jquery it can be done like this.

Include jquery plugin library in your code using the script tag

now you can edit the properties of html elements like this:

$("#IdOfTheElement").attr("NewProperty","NewValue");

Its that simple.

Comment: Setting styles without jQuery is already simple enough... recommending jQuery here does not help the OP to understand their mistake.

Comment: i'm using this to create a stylesheet